# Laravel login without register

Tags: laravel, authentication

Is it possible to login a user in Laravel 7 without having the user on the database? I have a group of users, which I don't want them on my database, because they use an external API to do the login and I can get their details from that API (via XML).

There are 3 types of users:

1. AR division users. Normal registered users.
2. Non-AR division users, but $user->gca = 1. Registered users too.
3. Non-AR division and Non-GCA users. **Non-registered users**.

All of them use an external API for the login. However, I only register the first 2 ones on my database for organisational purposes.

My intention is to use Laravel login using the 3rd type user details from the API without touching my database.

My code at LoginController.php

```
$user_array = json_decode(file_get_contents($this->api_url . '?type=json&token=' . $request->cookie($this->cookie_name)));

if ($user_array->result)
{
  $u = NULL;

  if ($user = User::find($user_array->vid)) $u = $user;
  else if($user_array->division == 'AR' || !is_null(Gca::find($user_array->vid)))
  {
    $u = new User();

    if(! is_null(Gca::find($user_array->vid))) $u->gca = 1;
    $u->name = $user_array->firstname;
    $u->vid = $user_array->vid;
    $vid = $u->vid;

    $u->save();

    return view('register', compact('vid'));
   }
   else
   {
    $user = new User();
    $user->division = $user_array->division;
    $user->vid = $user_array->vid;
    $user->name = $user_array->firstname;
    $user->surname = $user_array->lastname;

    Auth::login($user); //This doesn't seem to work.

    return redirect('/');
   }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: the default user provider uses a database and expects credentials to log in the user. what I think you can do is create a custom user provider: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#adding-custom-user-providers

Comment: Could you please provide more relevant information? eg `route`?

Comment: I have edited my post. Routes are not relevant, as they don't use authentication directly.

Comment: Thanks @Rabah!  You were right. had to create a custom provider and custom guard.